# Полутора, полтора?

Tags: стилистика

"Травма повлекла нетрудоспособность гражданина в течение более чем полутора месяцев(а)".

Полтора или полутора? Какое окончание в слове "месяц"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Существительное "месяц" имеет форму Р. п, числительное "полтора" согласуется с ним в падеже. Если числительное в родительном, дательном, творительном или предложном падеже, то существительное после него употребляется во множественном числе вне зависимости от того, какое именно числительное идёт перед ним ([источник](http://opencorpora.org/wiki/Снятие_неоднозначности_между_единственным_и_множественным_числом_у_существительных)). Учитывая все вышесказанное, нормативной является конструкция "полутора месяцев".

Answer (score 3):

Числительное ПОЛТОРА-ПОЛТОРЫ имеет следующие грамматические особенности:

1. И.-В.: значение РОДА выражено, сочетание с сущ.  в форме Р.п.  в ЕД. числе в виде исключения: полтора (два) месяца и полторы (две) недели.
2. Р.Д.Т.П.: значение рода НЕ ВЫРАЖЕНО,  сочетание с сущ.  в форме Р.п.   МН. числа (как для всех числительных):  более (Р.п.) полутора (двух) месяцев, недель.
3. Если сравнить числительные ПОЛТОРА и ДВА , то числительное ПОЛТОРА имеет только одну особенность: единую форму ПОЛУТОРА во всех косвенных падежах.
4. Согласование в счетном обороте происходит только в КОСВЕННЫХ падежах, когда НИ ОДНО числительное НЕ ИМЕЕТ ЗНАЧЕНИЯ РОДА, поэтому согласование по роду невозможно: два месяца, две недели, полтора месяца, полторы недели - более двух месяцев,недель, более полутора месяцев, недель.

Comment: Так было далеко не всегда :  
>В.Я.Шишков. Емельян Пугачев (1939-45) 
Все же остальные пленные ― а их **более полуторы тысяч** человек ― после увещаний были распущены по домам.  

>В.Г.Короленко. Марусина заимка (1899)  
А от Якутска до Колымска **более полуторы тысяч** верст!  

И с единственным числом имеется :  
> Г.И.Успенский. Поездки к переселенцам (1889)  
... но в нынешнем году бывали дни, когда в бараках скапливалось **более полуторы тысячи** переселенцев...

Нормы так быстро меняются в русском языке, что и не уследишь. Форма *полуторы* - чем не угодила нормоустроителям.

Comment: Такое впечатление, что слово раньше склонялось как прилагательное, поэтому выражало род в косвенных падежах. Особенно если вспомнить о его происхождении: полтора - древнерусское сращение полъ вътора - "один и половина второго". Это действительно так?

Comment: Полтретья = 2,5

Answer (score 2):

В И. и В.п. в сочетании **полтора (чего?) месяца** существительное  стоит в ед. ч. Р.п. (оно управляется числительным), но в других падежах, где уже существительное управляет числительным,  для него (существительного) применяется мн. число, по правилу сочетания с числительными 2,3,4 : **два дня - двух дней**.

> "числительное полтора во всех падежах, кроме именительного и винительного, сочетается с формой множественного числа последующего существительного."

*... в течение более чем полутора месяцев* (Р.п.)
В течение ... месяцев (Р.п.)(скольких?) {управление} более чем **полутора** (Р.п.)
Добавлю маленькую подробность) *В течение* - это предлог, употребляется всегда с Р.п.

Comment: Вы утверждаете, что "в других падежах... существительное управляет числительным". На мой взгляд, это не так: количественное числительное в словосочетании управляет существительным в именительном (винительном) падеже, являясь главным словом, и согласуется с существительным в остальных падежах, являясь зависимым словом.

Comment: Noir права, счетный оборот - это такое удивительное словосочетание, в котором главное и зависимое слово меняются местами.

Comment: >главное и зависимое слово меняются местами

Именно это я и утверждаю!))) 
Я пользовался вот такой известной подсказкой :  
>**При согласовании три требования** главного к зависимому - род, число, падеж.  
>**При управлении одно требование главного к зависимому - падеж.**  
 

В течение более чем **полутора месяцев**. Глав. слово *месяцев* управляет зависим. словом *полтора*, заставляя его принять форму род. падежа. Ни рода, ни числа в слове **полутора** мы разглядеть не можем, их НЕТ. Это не согласование, а чистое управление. Попробуйте доказать, что *полутора* - согласование в р., ч., п.

Comment: Попробуйте доказать согласование зависимого слова *полутора* в **роде, числе** и падеже одновременно - с главным словом *месяцев*.

Comment: "Полтора" - числительное - согласуется, как может.

Comment: Все грамматические числительные не имеют категории числа и редко имеют категорию рода, обычно у них только категория падежа. Пять месяцев - пяти месяцев - пятью месяцами, полтора месяца - полутора месяцев - полутора месяцами. Всё это согласование в падеже.

Comment: Числ. *полтора* как раз имеет формы двух родов (полтора/полторы), но согласовываться по роду в известных падежах не хочет, такое капризное. Оно вполне себе может согласоваться : более **полуторы тысяч**, но НЕ хочет, хоть ты тресни. Или ему кто-то умный **запретил** такое действие.
Задам вопрос : есть ли в РЯ слово **полуторы**, чтобы согласование было хотя бы по двум позициям - роду и падежу?